# Convert 4 channel image to 3 Channel image

Tags: opencv

I am using OpenCV 2.4.6. I am trying to convert a 4channel RGB IplImage to 4channel HSV image. Below is my code. Which is giving error "OpenCV Error: Assertion failed in unknown function". I think cvCvtColor supports 3channel images. Is there any way of converting 4channel RGB to HSV or 4channel RGB to 3channel RGB?

```
 IplImage*  mCVImageColor = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(640,480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
 /*Doing something*/
 IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(mCVImageColor), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
 cvCvtColor(mCVImageColor, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV); //This line throws exception
```

Comment: The Array operation `mixChannels` helped me.

Answer (score 11):

The common assumption is that the 4th channel is an alpha (A) channel. Thus, the correct conversion code is:

```
cvCvtColor(mCVImageColor, imgHSV, CV_BGRA2HSV);
```

Notice the **A** in **BGRA**.

Also, I guess from your syntax (mCVImage...) that you are using C++. Then, why not using the C++ API of OpenCV? 
If you choose to go C++, the documentation is still outdated, and you can find up-to-date color conversion codes for OpenCV 2.4.6 [here](http://www.computersdontsee.net/index.php/post/2013/06/11/Nouveaux-types-dans-OpenCV).

For your case, the correct color conversion code (C++) is: `cv::COLOR_BGRA2HSV`. But if you are using C++ API, then you should use `cv::Mat` objects and call the funciton `cv::cvtColor(...)` instead of using `IplaImage`'s and `cv` prefixed functions.

Comment: I am doing this now..But still cv::COLOR_BGRA2HSV is undefined         Mat b(mCVImageColor);
   Mat matHSV(mCVImageColor);
   cv::cvtColor(b, matHSV, cv::COLOR_BGRA2HSV);

Comment: But i have found COLOR_BGRA2BRG.after that I can do BGR2HSV. will the output be same as COLOR_BGRA2HSV??

Comment: You can use the direct code (BGRA ---> HSV) or do it by steps (BFRA ---> BGR ---> HSV). Bugs apart, the result will be the same (OpenCV ignores the alpha channel).

Answer (score 7):

Working with OpenCV 3.1, I had this issue but the answer by sansuiso was not working for me.

Instead, I went with the following command to convert from 4 channel color (RGBA) to 3 channel color (RGB):

```
cvtColor(inputMat, outputMat, CV_BGRA2BGR);
```

Afterwards, I verified the `channels()` for each type, and was able to confirm that the alpha channel had been stripped, and my function worked properly that required three channel images.

Answer (score -2):

I have a idea to remove the channel, to convert it to white. Then you can use opencv to do other operations. This method will use PIL package.

```
image = Image.open("original.png")
image.convert("RGBA") # Convert this to RGBA if possible

pixel_data = image.load()

if image.mode == "RGBA":
# If the image has an alpha channel, convert it to white
# Otherwise we'll get weird pixels
for y in range(image.size[1]): # For each row ...
    for x in range(image.size[0]): # Iterate through each column ...
        # Check if it's opaque
        if pixel_data[x, y][3] < 255:
            # Replace the pixel data with the colour white
            pixel_data[x, y] = (255, 255, 255, 255)
image.save("noAlphaChannelImage.png")
```